# Change img src on hover with preloaded gifs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onhover

I'm looking for a quick and easy way to preload gifs and then use these gifs on hover when you hover over an image swamping out the src of the image for the gif.

I was originally loading the gifs in the HTML but it makes for a slow load. my original code where the "src" for an image is changed on hover with "data-alt-src" is below:

**EDIT**

I've figured out how to preload the gif src into the DOM as an image while hiding it from being displayed. I would like for each image to be displayed into its respected HTML figure. Right now its loading all three gifs into the first  tag. how can i load it so only one gif loads into each . I have a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/renevilla23/jsxytp9b/4/). any help is appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<figure>
  <img src="http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/stills/FORD-SUPER-BOWL.jpg" data-alt-src="http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/gifs/giphy.gif"/>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/stills/OPERATOR.jpg" data-alt-src="http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/gifs/giphy.gif"/>
</figure>
```

**Javascript**

```
var sourceSwap = function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
    $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
    $this.attr('src', newSource);
}

$(function() {
    $('img[data-alt-src]').each(function() { 
        new Image().src = $(this).data('alt-src');
    }).fadeIn().hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
});
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/renevilla23/cv659exc/3/)

I was able to properly preload the gifs with the following code below, checking the console for a successful preload of the gifs.

**Javascript**

```
function preloader()
{
 // counter
  var i = 0;

  // create object
  imageObj = new Image();

 // set image list
  images = new Array();
  images[0]="http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/gifs/giphy.gif"
  images[1]="http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/gifs/LEAGUE-OF-LEGENDS.gif"
  images[2]="http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/gifs/OPERATOR.gif"

 // start preloading
  for(i=0; i<=2; i++) 
  {
      imageObj.src=images[i];
      console.log(images[i]);
  }
} 

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    preloader();
});
```

[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/renevilla23/qLhgb69j/) (loads the gifs in browser console - just to make sure the code works!)

I'm having trouble connecting the preloaded gifs, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery) as a reference to go through the array of preloaded gifs and swapping out the src with the gif src on hover, but I havent had success. Any insight and/or direction would be really appreciated as i'm new to coding and would love to learn how to do this. thanks!

**HTML**

```
<figure>
  <img src="http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/stills/FORD-SUPER-BOWL.jpg"/>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/stills/OPERATOR.jpg" />
</figure>
```

**Javascript**

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
            $(this).hover(function(){
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        });
    });
}



preload([
    "http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/gifs/giphy.gif",
      "http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/gifs/LEAGUE-OF-LEGENDS.gif",
      "http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/gifs/OPERATOR.gif"
]);
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/renevilla23/jsxytp9b/1/)

**EDIT**
so basically (i write this for my understanding too), im currently loading images and gifs at the same time, fiddle 1. I would like to preload the gifs so that when i hover over one of the images the corresponding preloaded gif gets swapped into the img src. Is this possible? I'm able to load the gifs in fiddle 2, but i am having a hard time connecting the available gifs that have been preloaded into the src attribute of the corresponding image. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should execute the `preload()` for each image elements.

Comment: @Yonggoo Nohi was trying to reference the [0] value from the preload below (.gif). can you explain what you mean please.

Comment: In the third line of your last js code, could you try to `console.log($(this))`?

Comment: I mean, that should be an image element which you want to attach `hover` event to. See [jQuery hover() docs](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: actually, yes it returns the following `["h", "t", "t", "p", ":", "/", "/", "r", "e", "n", "e", "i", "n", "l", "a", ".", "c", "o", "m", "/", "t", "a", "s", "h", "a", "-", "g", "o", "l", "d", "t", "h", "w", "a", "i", "t", "/", "s", "t", "y", "l", "e", "/", "i", "m", "a", "g", "e", "s", "/", "g", "i", "f", "s", "/", "g", "i", "p", "h", "y", ".", "g", "i", "f"]`

Comment: actually I would like to add hover to the html image using the preloaded gifs to swap into the html src on hover.

Answer (score 0):

I have using id of the images as numericals whose corresponding index in the array (arrayOfImages) is the src of your gif;

Hope this helps

```js
let images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
 
 for(i=0 ; i<images.length; i++) {
  images[i].onmouseover  = function() {getIdAndLoadGif(this)};
 } 

 function getIdAndLoadGif(e) {  
  loadGif(e.getAttribute('id'));
 }

 function loadGif(imgId) {  
  document.getElementById(imgId).src= arrayOfImages[imgId];
 }
 
 let arrayOfImages = ["http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/gifs/giphy.gif",
      "http://s3.amazonaws.com/barkpost-assets/50+GIFs/17.gif",
      "http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/gifs/OPERATOR.gif"];
```

```css
figure img{
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/stills/FORD-SUPER-BOWL.jpg" id="0"/>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="https://assets.babycenter.com/ims/2016/09/iStock_83513033_4x3.jpg" id="1"/>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://reneinla.com/tasha-goldthwait/style/images/stills/OPERATOR.jpg" id="2"/>
</figure>
```